# turn array of array into readable json in python3

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

```
c = [ ['1','2'] ,['1','3'],['1','4'] ]
obj = {}
for x in c :
    obj[x[0]]={'num':[*obj[x[0]['num']  ,x[1]]}
print(obj)
```

I am trying to turn this array of arrays into :
{1 : {num : [2,3,4]}}

Comment: If the code isn't doing what you want, please explain what it does instead, and how that differs from what you wanted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Neither your posted code nor your desired output is syntactically legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While iterating over `c` check if `x[0]` is already a key in the dictionary. If it is not in the dictionary then create the index and add a list with `x[1]` as the initial value. If it is in the dictionary then just append `x[1]` to the list.

```
c = [ ['1','2'] ,['1','3'],['1','4'] ]
obj = {}
for x in c :
    if x[0] in obj:
        obj[x[0]]["num"].append(x[1])
    else:
        obj[x[0]] = {"num": [x[1]]}
print(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `c` as key-value pairs, and keep appending the values to the sub-dict created using `setdefault` with the respective key:

```
obj = {}
for k, v in c:
    obj.setdefault(k, {}).setdefault('num', []).append(v)
```

so that `obj` becomes:

```
{'1': {'num': ['2', '3', '4']}}
```